AWS Lambda Error : No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg
I had a running Lambda function on python 3.6 but when I updated the runtime environment from Python 3.6 to Python 3.9 I am getting the following error.
I also updated the Lambda Layers to 3.9 but still getting the error.
What else should I try to resolve this issue. Before the upgrade the function was running fine.
ERROR:
Test Event Name
testLambda

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'av-oa-moa-hana-shortages': No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "6d3c186e-74c5-4fd3-907a-c1506476ba9b",
  "stackTrace": []
}

Function Logs
/opt/python/jmespath/visitor.py:32: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
if x is 0 or x is 1:
/opt/python/jmespath/visitor.py:32: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
if x is 0 or x is 1:
/opt/python/jmespath/visitor.py:34: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
elif y is 0 or y is 1:
/opt/python/jmespath/visitor.py:34: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
elif y is 0 or y is 1:
/opt/python/jmespath/visitor.py:260: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
if original_result is 0:
START RequestId: 6d3c186e-74c5-4fd3-907a-c1506476ba9b Version: $LATEST
LAMBDA_WARNING: Unhandled exception. The most likely cause is an issue in the function code. However, in rare cases, a Lambda runtime update can cause unexpected function behavior. For functions using managed runtimes, runtime updates can be triggered by a function change, or can be applied automatically. To determine if the runtime has been updated, check the runtime version in the INIT_START log entry. If this error correlates with a change in the runtime version, you may be able to mitigate this error by temporarily rolling back to the previous runtime version. For more information, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-update.html
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'av-oa-moa-hana-shortages': No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'
Traceback (most recent call last):END RequestId: 6d3c186e-74c5-4fd3-907a-c1506476ba9b
REPORT RequestId: 6d3c186e-74c5-4fd3-907a-c1506476ba9b  Duration: 3.60 ms   Billed Duration: 4 ms   Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 56 MB  Init Duration: 615.23 ms

Request ID
6d3c186e-74c5-4fd3-907a-c1506476ba9b


Does the new layer include psycopg2 and is it compatible with the newer version of Python?

How did you baked your new Lambda layer? Did you use an x84_x64 or ARM computer to build the layers? What is the operating system of the computer? What is the compute architecture of your function?

I am using psycopg2==2.8.3 in the Lambda layer

I think psycopg2==2.8.3 is not compatible with python 3.9 it only supports till 3.7
